# Fix background panel using Teechart

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, teechart

We are currently using Teechart libraries to draw signals to display moving waves on a canvas. good news is everything works fine so far. I want to fix the   position for signals on canvas. we can move the panel behind on which signal is flowing,when we use right click on the canvas. i want to fix the position of panel/background on which signal is moving. I am newbie using tee chart library. any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at the demo [here](http://www.steema.com/files/public/teechart/html5/latest/demos/axes/zoomscroll.htm) to see how to disable the scroll/zoom.

Comment: Thanks for the guideline. I was looking for something very similar :)